# Setting restriction to `mixed` element

Tags: xml, xsd, libxml2

Hello I want to be able to define something like this:

```
<Infos>
      <Mileage>9987
          <UseIn>POS_DISPLAY</UseIn>
          <UseIn>READER_DISPLAY</UseIn>
      </Mileage>
</Infos>
```

`Mileage` is mixed type. `9987` is its value, and `UseIn` are some properties.
The problem is that I can't find a way to define restriction for `Mileage` content.

Is there any way to define the structure above, without falling back to:

```
<Infos>
      <Mileage>
          <MileageValue>9987</MileageValue>
          <UseIn>POS_DISPLAY</UseIn>
          <UseIn>READER_DISPLAY</UseIn>
      </Mileage>
</Infos>
```

Comment: How are you restricted? By a schema? By a DTD? By RelaxNG? Post the code that shows your restriction. There is nothing, technically, that should prevent mixing text nodes with element nodes, if you are defining the document format yourself.

Comment: @DaveJarvis: Yes, it is XSD schema that validates this format. I am at home now, but tommorow I will post XSD definition here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For historical reasons I won't bother to describe, XSD types with mixed content allow character data to appear at any location.  It's easy to define a type that allows the structure you show, but it's not so easy to define a type that allows what you show while rejecting variants like

```
<Mileage>
    <UseIn>POS_DISPLAY</UseIn>
    9987
    <UseIn>READER_DISPLAY</UseIn>
</Mileage>
```

or

```
<Mileage>99
    <UseIn>POS_DISPLAY</UseIn>
    8
    <UseIn>READER_DISPLAY</UseIn>
    7
</Mileage>
```

My advice, fwiw, is to fall back to the second design, which will work better with most XML infrastructure.